# How do you access the title (Node module element) field in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a computed field in a Drupal 7 content type that is populated by my description (text) field:

```
$entity_field[0]['value'] = $entity->field_desciption['und'][0]['value'];
```

It works fine. I want to create another computed field that is populated by the title (Node module element) field.

I tried with the following lines, but they don't work.

```
$entity_field[0]['value'] = $entity->title['und'][0]['value'];
```

```
$entity_field[0]['value'] = $node->title;
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The node title is not a field; therefore, using `$entity->title['und'][0]['value']` will not work. What you should use is `$entity->title`.

As side note, to get the value of a field, you should use [field_get_items()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7), which takes care of the language set for the field, which isn't necessarily `LANGUAGE_NONE`.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a node module element, it should be accessible via `$entity->title` directly.
Try a `print_r($entity); die;` to get all elements of the entity. Hope this help you.

Comment: i would highly recommend installing devel module and using 
dpm($variable_you_want_to_inspect);
its use the excellent krumo library to display the array, so it becomes easier to inspect.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at printing the array/object to the page to see what you are working with exactly.

Try adding `print_r($entity);` or `print_r($node);` to the page where the entity or node is displayed followed by `exit;`

You can then right click the page and click 'View page source' to display the output in a structured format. Use this to see the variable names, object/array types and hierachy to then write your full variable code correctly.

```
print_r($node);
exit;
```

I would imagine it should have been $node->title though...